# How to get value of a specific column in OnRowDataBound function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridviewcolumn, gridviewrow

I have a dropdown and a gridview. Depending on the value selected in the dropdown, I want to update the NaviagetURL for the hyperlink specified in 1st column of the gridview. So I am using onRowDataBound function to update the hyperlink's navigateurl dynamically. And, I am trying to retrieve value of first column "ID" to use it as the query string inside the OnRowDataBound function but I am not able to get this working.

When I click on the hyperlink in the first column, the query string doesn't have any value assigned to the variable ID. So, the url just resolves to http://localhost/JobCosting/EditSavedTicket.aspx?ID=

What is expected is, the url which opens on clicking the hyperlink should have the value specified in 1st column assigned to the variable ID in the query string. If I use e.Row.Cells[1].Text or e.Row.Cells[2].Text, the column value is being retrieved correctly, but I need the value in column zero which is not getting retrieved. When I check the length of the string id which is e.Row.Cells[0].Text, it is zero

**GridView:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
 AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="Saved_Work" OnRowDataBound="update_url" 
 Style="float: left; font-size: small; position: relative;
            width: 82%; position: relative; top: -10px; height: 40px; font-size: small; text-align: left;
            left: 30px;" align="left">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="Continue_SavedWork" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "~/EditSavedJob.aspx?ID={0}") %>'
                            Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="User" SortExpression="UserID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Created" HeaderText="Last_Updated_On" SortExpression="Date_Created" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void update_url(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //string NavigateUrl="<%# Eval('ID', 'EditSavedTicket.aspx?ID={0}) %>";
        string id = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        HyperLink hp = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("Continue_SavedWork");
        if (SavedWorkDD.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Tickets")
            hp.NavigateUrl = string.Format("EditSavedTicket.aspx?ID={0}", id);
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens?

Comment: Hi @MarkMiller, I have updated the post.

Comment: Why do you need the OnRowDataBound event handler? The URL is set as expected by databinding if you remove the event handler.

Comment: @Markus, I have updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the reason why you can't access the text of the first column is that it is a template column whereas the other columns are `BoundField` columns.

Instead of retrieving the text from the controls, you can access the `DataItem` in your `OnRowUpdated` event handler. For instance, if you are binding to a DataTable, you can access the `DataRowView` like this:

```
protected void update_url(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    var row = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
    var id = (int)row["ID"];
    // ...
  }
}
```

This approach is more reliant than trying to find the controls and accessing their values. It will continue to work even if you change the UI.